# How to change app icon for app store in xamarin.forms for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, app-store, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I created an iOS app in xamarin.forms. Now I am trying to upload it on app store. When I upload it through Applicaton loader and go to the itunes account to check the build app there. I found that the app icon of that build is not correct. It is showing xamarin image there. I changed the image in app from going Options->iOS Applicaton and then change the image in itunes artwork. I changed both images 512X512 and 1024X1024, but still I am getting the same xamarin image there.

Can anyone tell me how I can change that xamarin image with my app image?

Answer (score 2):

The 512x512 and 1024x1024 images are the so-called iTunesArtwork images. If I'm not mistaken they aren't really used and if they are it is somewhere within iTunes.

There are a variety of other images that you should replace to set the app icon.
Within Xamarin Studio double-click on the `info.plist` file to bring up the editor and scroll down to the 'Universal Icons' (or 'iPhone Icons' or 'iPad Icons' if you're targeting only one platform).

There is a dropdown there which looks like this;

[image: App icons dropdown]

There are basically two options;

1. Set it to 'Don't user Asset Catalogs' and click all the boxes below to set the app icons in all sizes (ProTip; use [makeappicon.com](http://makeappicon.com/))
2. Set it to a Asset Catalog file. You can add it under your Resources folder (right-click > 'Add' > 'New File') if there isn't one already.

[image: Add new Asset Catalog]

After the file is created double-click that one and another editor comes up. Also here just fill in all the boxes with the right icon.